# How to retrieve the value of ng2-timepicker in angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I have implemented a timepicker in  my program. And facing an issue. I have taken the code from :
[ng2-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-timepicker)

Timepicker contains a code snippet :

```
open() {
    const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open();
    amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe(time => {
      console.log("AMAZING TIMEPICKER TIME",time);
    });
}
```

however, if i put the above code in -->  ngOnInit() or a function say --> searchByText(data_filterdata) , the above mentioned code in open() pops up suddendly . How to stop its sudden appearance and only on the open() function code sudden appearance am i able to obtain its value. I tried to include open() in function searchByText (...) , but again it suddenly appears as soon as i click on the button linked to the function searchByText. I want to retrieve the value of time variable in open(). how to do that

Comment: I've tried to fix your post, but there are just too many unknowns. You are often referring to "it": what are you referring to? And what "value" are you referring to? Did you remove the logger code?

Comment: hi JHBonarius .... i have corrected the sentences.please check

Comment: The question is: what do you want to achieve? Why did you use the code from timepicker? The whole purpose of the code you show is to open the popup. That is why it is called `open()`. Read the [API manual](https://owsolutions.github.io/amazing-time-picker/API). So if you don't want the popup, don't use `open()`.

Comment: Look at the example [here, at "Opening component programmatically"](https://owsolutions.github.io/amazing-time-picker/Examples) on how to store the selected time in a local variable, which you can then use without having to open the popup again.